# Creme 96, Python, Mechanize.py

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to login to the CREME 96 website to get data from the web app using python and mechanize module, I am new to web scraping so this is my first attempt at such a project.

this is the link to the login page: https://creme.isde.vanderbilt.edu/CREME-MC/login_form

the following is my code:

```
import mechanize

cj=mechanize.CookieJar()
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
browser.open("https://creme.isde.vanderbilt.edu/CREME-MC/login_form")
browser.select_form(nr = 1)
browser.form['__ac_name'] = Username
browser.form['__ac_password'] = Password
browser.submit()
```

I can not get this code to work. Please help.

Comment: Showing the error might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
browser['__ac_name'] = Username
browser['__ac_password'] = Password
```

Instead of:

```
browser.form['__ac_name'] = Username
browser.form['__ac_password'] = Password
```